# Android LiveData value not dispatched coming from background

Tags: android, android-livedata

Reading the `LiveData` documentation found [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#the_advantages_of_using_livedata), I came across this section:

> If a lifecycle becomes inactive, it receives the latest data upon becoming active again. For example, an activity that was in the background receives the latest data right after it returns to the foreground.

When I create a blank project to test this, I discover that latest data is not dispatched when coming from background.

Sample code from `onCreate()`:

```
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel::class.java)

button.setOnClickListener {
    viewModel.buttonClicked()
}

viewModel.textLiveData.observe(this, Observer {
    textview.text = it
    Log.d("TEST", "new data = $it")
})
```

When going to background and coming back, should the latest data that the `LiveData` is holding be dispatched again to the observer?

UPDATE:

ViewModel code as requested:

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {

    val textLiveData = MutableLiveData<String>()

    fun buttonClicked() {
        textLiveData.value = "new text value"
    }
}
```

Comment: it should yes, show your viewmodel

Comment: @tyczj I have added the ViewModel code although it's pretty basic

Comment: it won't if onCreate is not called and have a brand new observer registered to that LiveData. Another way of getting what you want is if something updates the livedata while your app was in background and then becoming active.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, after a lot of investigation, I will share my answer using two scenarios to make it easier to grasp

Scenario 1:

- App is in foreground
- `Observer` receives latest data change from `LiveData`
- App goes to background
- When coming back from background, `LiveData` will **NOT** dispatch the value since the `Observer` already consumed/has the latest change.

Scenario 2:

- App is in foreground
- Observer receives latest data change from `LiveData`
- App goes to background.
- While App is in background, LiveData receives a new value.
- Since App is still in background and `Observer` is not in an active state, `LiveData` will not dispatch the value change yet.
- When coming back to foreground and `Observer` is in an active state again, `LiveData` does dispatch the latest value since it has changed

Comment: Yes. This is the right behaviour. Also if there are multiple live datas that need to post data when App comes to foreground, they all post together. Make sure that in your activity you are not expecting liveData1 should come before liveData2.

Comment: In my case it is still not working, i do fragment navigation, using shared viewmodel. FragmentB post value, and FragmentA receives update. A starts B then popBackStack() to A. if i add delay before observing it works, assuming that it is only working if fragment is in foreground and not in background (as oppose to scenario 2)